# jenkins http request, variables on requestbody

Tags: jenkins

I am using httprequest plugin on jenkis to work with API. I am trying to insert a variable on the requesbody but the variable is not resolved. It is considering the variable as a string.

```
timestamps {


node () {
    
    def console_api = 'https://example.com/zyx'
    def console_address = 'example.com'
    
       stage ('download ') {
   
   httpRequest authentication: 'sa', httpMode: 'POST', ignoreSslErrors: true, outputFile: 'output.yaml', requestBody: ''' {
   "consoleAddr": "${console_address}",

  }''', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: "${console_api}/api/v1/daemonset.yaml", wrapAsMultipart: false
```

I need consoleAddr to be resolved to  example.com on the http request body.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use triple double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') in request body:

> httpRequest authentication: 'sa', httpMode: 'POST', ignoreSslErrors:
> true, outputFile: 'output.yaml', requestBody: """ {
> "consoleAddr":
> "${console_address}",
> }""",
>
> responseHandle: 'NONE', url:
> "${console_api}/api/v1/daemonset.yaml", wrapAsMultipart: false